# How can I loop over all directories and subdirectories and find files with a specific extension, then run FFMPEG on them, then copy them to a new lib

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, files, ffmpeg

Ive been researching all of today and yesterday trying to find a solution, none have worked for me so far.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784661/how-do-you-convert-an-entire-directory-with-ffmpeg

I want to be able to loop over all files in a folder (such as `/Music/`), find any files in any directory or subdirectory that ends with `.flac`, then convert those flac files to alac files using this command:

`ffmpeg -i "$i" -c copy -acodec alac "${i%.*}.m4a"`

the $i variable is the "name" of the file from the for loop. `${i%.*}` should just return the name, not the .flac portion.

Anyways, after that command has been run, I want all of those saved .m4a alac files to then be sent to a "new library"... IE: Ill have two `/Music/` libraries.

One has all the flac files

One has all the alac (m4a) files

Is this possible?

This is the commmand I have so far, definitely doesnt work, and even if it did, it doesnt create a new library like I want: `for i in *.flac; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c copy -acodec alac "${i%.*}.m4a"; done`

Currently that command just throws the error `*.flac: No such file or directory`, which I assume is because its not searching subdirectories?...

Comment: You may use find. Here is an example: https://askubuntu.com/a/898121/333867 You need to adapt it from convert to ffmpeg.

Comment: Use `find` and maybe `xargs`. Note: Unix does not have file-name-extensions. It is just a naming convention. (This is also true of MS windows, since Windows-95. But the file-explorer still uses them. )

Comment: Paths of converted files in the new directory should be the same as in the original Music directory? For example, an original file path `Music/one/two/song.flac` should be repeated in `New_Music`, like `New_Music/one/two/song.m4a`? Or `New_Music` should have just heap of files?

Comment: matching paths, just a new root folder, such as "Music2" or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

src_dir="Music"
dest_dir="Music_new"

for orig_path in "${src_dir}"/**/*.flac; do
    #Change first directory in the path
    new_path=${orig_path/$src_dir/$dest_dir}

    #Remove filename from new path. Only directories are left.
    #They are needed for mkdir
    dir_hier=${new_path%/*}

    #Remove extension .flac from path, thus we have original path with first directory
    #changed and file extension removed.
    #Original path:   "Music/one/two/song.flac"
    #New path:        "Music_new/one/two/song"
    new_path=${new_path%.*}

    echo mkdir -p "$dir_hier"

    #New path with extension:   "Music_new/one/two/song.m4a"
    #ffmpeg should create new file by this path, necessary directories
    #already created by mkdir
    echo ffmpeg -i "$orig_path" -c copy -acodec alac "${new_path}.m4a"
done
```

`echo` before `mkdir` and `ffmpeg` should be removed after checking.

Comment: removed echos, and it appears to work.